# Overload method in Application.java Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, overloading

How to set Overloading method in Application.java on Play Project?

Here is some example what I'm currently doing:

**Application.java**

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        render();
    }

    public static void getData() {
        renderText("Without Parameter");
    }

    public static void getData(String name) {
        renderText("With Parameter name = " + name);
    }
}
```

**routes**

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                                       Application.index
GET     /data                                   Application.getData

# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

**The Test:**

1. Call `getData` without parameter `http://localhost:9000/data`
2. Call `getData` with parameter `http://localhost:9000/data?name=test`

**The Result:**

1. With Parameter name = null
2. With Parameter name = test

**What I want for the result:**

1. Without Parameter
2. With Parameter name = test

I'm very appreciated with your helps. Thank you...

---

## **Update Solution**

Here is what I'm doing based on [Daniel Alexiuc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409340/overload-method-in-application-java-play-framework/10409629#10409629) suggestion:

**Application.java**

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        render();
    }

    public static void getData() {
        /** 
         *  Do some process before call getDataName method 
         *  and send the result of the process as the parameter.
         *  That's why I do this way that look like redundancy process.
        **/
        getDataName(null);
    }

    public static void getDataName(String name) {
        // Didn't use ternary operation here because will become error 'not a statement'
        if(name == null)
            renderText("Without Parameter");
        else
            renderText("With Parameter name = " + name);
    }

}
```

**routes**

```
GET     /                                       Application.index
GET     /default                                Application.getData
GET     /dataString                             Application.getDataName
```

---

## **Update Solution (26/07)**

**Application.java**

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        render();
    }

    public static void getData(String name, Integer age) {
        if (name == null && age == null) {
            renderText("Data null");
        } else if (name != null && age == null) {
            renderText("Name: " + name);
        } else if (name != null && age != null) {
            renderText("Name: " + name + "\n" + "Age: " + age);
        }
    }
}
```

**routes**

```
GET     /data                                   Application.getData
GET     /data/{name}                            Application.getData
GET     /data/{name}/{age}                      Application.getData
```

And for the call:

```
 1. http://localhost:9000/data                -> Display "Data null"
 2. http://localhost:9000/data/Crazenezz      -> Display "Name: Crazenezz"
 3. http://localhost:9000/data/Crazenezz/24   -> Display "Name: Crazenezz
                                                          Age: 24"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to overload it in the routes file like you want.

but you could just do something like this:

```
public static void getData(String name) {
  if (name == null) {
    renderText("Without Parameter");
  } else {
    renderText("With Parameter name = " + name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, let see what the other expert says for this problem is it possible or not to do.

Comment: I tried many ways and didn't find any other possible. So I choose to do with your style :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I wanted to achieve the same thing as you, Crazenezz, so first I tried with the following route definition:

```
GET     /terms.json                 controllers.exposedjson.TermServiceJSON.findTermsByQuery(langId:Long ?= null)
```

... together with a method in the controller which checked whether the argument was null or not, but that failed since `null` was not a valid optional value in the route definition. So instead I believe I will go with the following solution (which works so far), exposing a string value in the JSON service interface which I casted to a long in the controller.

```
GET     /terms.json                 controllers.exposedjson.TermServiceJSON.findTermsByQuery(langId:String ?= "")


@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public static Result findTermsByQuery(String languageId) {
    Result result;
    if (languageId == "")
        result = ok(toJson(TermService.getTerms()));
    else
        result = ok(toJson(TermService.findTermsByLanguageId(Long.parseLong(languageId.trim()))));
    return result;
}
```

It is not very pretty, but from the service client perspective it may be better than using two separate paths.

Comment: After I tried your suggestion with 3 overload method, I found that the parameter `langId:Long ?= null` didn't really useful. It supposed written like this `langId:'5'`, it was static value and if user request the `/terms.json` without parameter it will pass `5` as the default value. You can check your command-prompt or terminal that the `langId:Long ?= null is ignore` if you still use the configuration above. For the first I think that this is what I want, but after testing again and again I come with another solution, please see my update solution above. Btw nice try... :)